# Swipe to delete item from listView: getting error Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorListenerCompat;

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, sql-delete

I have a RecyclerView powered by a Room database. I want to add a swipe to delete function on the list, but whenever I swipe I get the following error:

```
2018-10-31 20:10:47.607 3613-3613/com.andygix.programarilucia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.andygix.programarilucia, PID: 3613
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorListenerCompat;
    at com.andygix.programarilucia.AppointmentListFullView.onCreate(AppointmentListFullView.java:50)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.animation.AnimatorListenerCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.andygix.programarilucia.AppointmentListFullView.onCreate(AppointmentListFullView.java:50) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.andygix.programarilucia-x3B7sSOmUwFsUh9BkB3PXA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:75)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:38)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:716)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:749)
```

Also, it creates a new field with the last values entered in the Room database.

```
new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                appointmentViewModel.delete(adapter.getAppointmentAtPos(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                Toast.makeText(context, "Programarea a fost stearsa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(appointmentList);
```

As far as I see, there seems to be a compatibility issue (although not sure) because the error is for *support/v4* while I use *v7* in the gradle file.

My gradle.app file looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.andygix.programarilucia"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

    // Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
}
```

Any ideas on how I can make the swipe to delete to work without changing the support version number?

Comment: What's the full stacktrace? Also, `v4` vs `v7` aren't mutually exclusive. The numbers reference the minimum API those libraries work on.

Comment: Totally noob thing to ask, but what is a stacktrace? I presume it has something to do with the logcat, case in which what do I need to paste in here?

Comment: It's the rest of that error. There should be indented lines below it, starting with `at` or `caused by`.

Comment: add your build.gradle (Module: app) file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this at the end

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            // Skip multidex because it follows a different versioning pattern.
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

of app module `build.gradle`

Comment: Tried it and I can't build the project. I am getting:
`Android resource linking failed
Output:  D:\Dev\Main\ProgramariLucia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.` 
And a few more like these

Comment: try with implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' only

Comment: Had that block of code but outside the android block. Unfortunately, I am getting two new errors for the activities that involve the database: `error: incompatible types: [ACTIVITY] cannot be converted to LifecycleOwner`

Comment: LifecycleOwner was added in support library 26.1.0. update your support library

Comment: Worked, finally. LifecycleOwner generated a few more errors, but after scoping the web got an idea about what it does and managed to implement this in the app without other bugs.